# how to get logged in user name from window service

Tags: wcf, service

how to get logged in user name from window service. when i do the same thing using Environment.UserName i get username as "System".

thanks 
Arvind

Answer (score 2):

You get System because your service runs under the System account.

There is an article on codeproject that discusses the same thing .. check it out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Windows_Service.aspx

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] objArrProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
string strCurrentUserName = objArrProcess[0].StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["username"];
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link which talks about getting current loggedin user from window service -

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3460184.php

Taken from above link itself -

> There can be 0 or more current logged in users. If you want all of the 0 or
>   1 users who are currently logged in at the console then P/Invoke to
>   WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId and WTSQuerySessionInformation. If you want
>   all of the users then you'll need to call WTSQuerySessionInformation in a
>   loop.