# how to get logged in user and machine name from window service in c#?

Tags: windows-services, wcf

How to get the logged in user (interactive user) and machine name from window service in c#. When i try Environment and other class to get logged in user name it just returns NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM from window service.

Comment: It's SYSTEM user who is running your service, that's why you get NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. To get machine name, you can use either  System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name or  Environment.MachineName

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get logged in user name from window service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837656/how-to-get-logged-in-user-name-from-window-service)

Comment: By the way, if you need to check all other users that's currently logged on the system, checkout this forum: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31897783/there-can-be-0-or-more-current-logged-in-users.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The service executes under the SYSTEM account, so that what you see in the `Environment` class. The machine name should not be a problem (see Gmoliv's comment). Services execute independently from whoever may be logged on: that's one of the main reasons to have them.

If you want to find out what users (yes, there may be more than one) may be logged on to your computer, you'll have to use raw Windows API's AFAIK. If you really want this, one way could be to [iterate through desktops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682644), [open the named desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684303), get the associated [user of each desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683238), and [look up the account name of the user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166) (which returns the account name on the local machine). If you only want the user which may see something on screen, use [OpenInputDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684309) to get a handle instead of iterating through all of them.

Note that this requires your service to have higher access rights than usual. I'd be a bit suspicious of such a service myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet

```
ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\cimv2");
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ms, query);
foreach(ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(mo["UserName"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach (at least, using `Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition` and `.Net Framework 4.7`) --

Namespace: `System.Security.Principal`

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

The above will give you:

> `COMPUTERNAME\username`

#### UPDATE

Yet another approach would be to use `Environment` as in--

> `Console.WriteLine(Environment.UserName);`
> which will yield logged-in user's *username*

and

> `Console.WriteLine(Environment.MachineName);`
> which will yield the *computer*'s or *machine*'s *name*